# Should I check for valid file extension at server even if I use 'accept' with v-file-input

Tags: html, vuetify.js

I am using **v-file-input** with 'accept' option, e.g.

```
<v-file-input
   :accept=".docx, .txt, image/*     ",
   label="Choose Attachment"
   name="file0" 
   id="file0"
></v-file-input>
```

This works and does not allow a file to be selected outside the defined 'accept' file types. The question is that is it still recommended to check for the valid file extension at the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most frontend validations for data being added to an endpoint request can be bypassed by making the request outside of your app using programs like Postman. Setting up CORS on your backend can mitigate that specific risk...  However, you can never be too safe. If it's a security risk or concern at all, always validate on the backend.

Comment: I am using Laravel framework and CORS is setup. My application will allow most common filetypes (images, documents, audio, video) to be uploaded. These files will be saved on AWS S3 and will be downloaded from some other part of the application.